# What is meant by a preliminary run at the LHC?

Tags: particle-physics, terminology, large-hadron-collider

I am a bit confused over the meaning of "Preliminary run" when referring to the LHC experiments CMS and ATLAS.

For example in [this summary](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.02544v1), Figure 2 refers to both the CMS $19.7\ \mathrm{fb^{-1}}$ data at $8\ \mathrm{TeV}$ and ATLAS $4.6\ \mathrm{fb^{-1}}$ data at $7\ \mathrm{TeV}$ as "Preliminary":

[image: Fig. 2 in arXiv:1507.02544v1]

Which run does the term "Preliminary run" refer to? Or is it used to mean something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "preliminary" does not refer to the runs. It refers to the status of results and figures that have not been properly reviewed and/or approved for publication yet.

Comment: In other words it's the analysis that is preliminary, not the raw data.